# Input HTML tag - how to enable checkbox while selecting file in OS file picker?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, windows, operating-system

A feature allows user to select multiple files using HTML input field. "Checkbox" appears for multiple file selection in OS based file picker. This is controlled through setting in Windows (as in snapshot File Browser -> Options -> View -> Use Check boxes to select items). This setting is not enabled for all users by-default. We want to enable it while showing user a File-Picker created through input HTML tag. Is there a way to control/enable this setting through HTML tag configuration or through Javascript while user is selecting files?

[image: OS setting to configure to view checkbox while selecting file]

[image: File selection - Checkbox visible while setting ON]

Comment: The closest thing is to use the 'multiple' attribute with the input

Comment: Already using `multiple=true` attribute to allow multiple file selection, but the checkbox being show is controlled through OS settings. Without checkbox multiple files can be selected, though checkbox is more explciit and hence we are looking to by-default ON it.

Comment: Another thing you could try is using the FileSystem api (https://web.dev/file-system-access/) and try using a directory picker, then displaying the files in the directory in a custom dialog. Of course this will limit your users to using Chrome (and maybe Safari)